# I am new to Azure SQL DataBase. Can any one tell me What is Compute Cost/ VCORE /Second 0.000175

Tags: azure

I am new to Azure SQL DataBase. Can any one tell me What is Compute Cost/ VCORE /Second 0.000175

[image]

i want to know total bill of my azure account per month.

Comment: Please refer [Compute costs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-sql/database/purchasing-models?view=azuresql#compute-costs)

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps [this MS learn document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/azure/azure-sql/database/serverless-tier-overview?view=azuresql) might be of use.

I believe you define a minimum and maximum amount of vcores used and it automatically scales between them based on requests. They are billed per second of usage. When there are no requests/no usage there are no vcores active.

[image]